# jQuery Slideshow: load paused, start with link issue

Tags: jquery, cycle

I've seen similar problems to mine, but not exactly. 
My page has multiple cycle slideshows running on it, so I don't want them to all start at once. 
I'd like to load them paused, then start when clicking a simple link. Here's what I've come up with:

```
$('#s2').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    speed: 2000,
    pause:  1,
    pager:  '#speakerTwoNav',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, el) {
        return '<a href="#"></a>';
    }
}).cycle('pause');
    $('#speakerInfoChipKiddLink').click(function(){
    $('#s2').cycle('resume');
});
```

This is an example of one of the slideshows. `#s2` is the name of it, and `#speakerInfoChipKidd` is the id of the link I want to start the slideshow.

I'm not getting errors with this code, it's just not pausing it right away.

Answer (score 0):

Separate out the initialise and the pause :

```
$('#s2').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    speed: 2000,
    pause:  1,
    pager:  '#speakerTwoNav',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, el) {
        return '<a href="#"></a>';
    }
});

$('#s2').cycle('pause');
```